# Could not complete cursor operation because the table schema changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two stored procedures running at the same time.

One of these procedure make an ALTER TABLE on table1

In my second procedure, I make a cursor on table1 like this:

```
select client_number
from table1
```

And I loop into my cursor.

But because I have the alter table in my first stored procedure, I have this message :

> Could not complete cursor operation because the table schema changed

What can I do?

Comment: This feels like 2 [XY Problem](http://xyprolem.info)s in one. Why are you `ALTER`ing the table in a Procedure? Surely if it runs once the next time it runs it'll fail; due to the change you are making already happening. As for the other, why use a `CURSOR` here? SQL is a set based language, so you would be far better off with a set based solution.

Comment: Absolutely as Larnu says, changing your schema willy nilly in an SP like is asking for trouble.